# Dictionary search results in key error in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I've looked up similar stackoverflow questions but none are quite like this. 
Quite simply, I have the following code that seeks to look up a dictionary for a username and corresponding password. If they match, then access granted and go to the loggedin function, else access denied.

Having set it up like below, it works perfectly when the credentials are correct, but on getting them wrong, results in a key error:

**Code**

```
username=input("Enter username:")
                     password=input("Enter password:")

                     accessgranted=False
                     while accessgranted==False:
                         if userinfo_dict[username]==password:
                             loggedin()
                             accessgranted==True
                         else:
                             break
                     print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
                     main()
```

**Error**

```
   if userinfo_dict[username]==password:
KeyError: 'ee'
```

**The file is simply:**

```
user1,pass1
user2,pass2
```

Could someone please
a) Correct and comment on the error
b) Suggest alternative or more efficient ways of achieving the same thing

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen when the `dict` doesn't contain the key? That is the source of the error...

Comment: you should try to use `userinfo_dict.get(username, 'not found')` to work around this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check that both the username and passwords are in the dictionary and that they are a key-value pair, with the following:

```
#Check that both username and password in dictionary
if username in userinfo_dict.keys() and password in userinfo_dict.values():
    if userinfo_dict[username] == password:
        accessgranted = True
else:
    print('Access Denied') #Print if either username or password not in dictionary
```

The `keys()` method returns a list of the keys in the dictionary whereas the `values()` method returns a list of the values in the dictionary.

Comment: This is very inefficient. Better to use the `.get` method, or just a `try-except`. Note, there never really is a point in checking if the password is in `userinfo_dict.values()`. And in Python2, this makes your algorithm linear rather than constant-time.

Comment: I need it to be in Python 3. juanpa - if you have a more efficient method, could you please post it as an answer. Thankyou Henry, this works....so just waiting for anything else or will accept it.

Comment: `if username in userinfo_dict and userinfo_dict[username] == password: ...`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as many others already pointed out, you are trying to get the value for a non-existing key.

An easy workaround would be to check if `userinfo_dict[username] == password` only if `username` is an existing key.

```
username = input("Enter username:")
password = input("Enter password:")

access_granted = False
while access_granted is False:
    if username in userinfo_dict.keys() and userinfo_dict[username] == password:
        loggedin()
        access_granted = True
    else:
        break
print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
main()
```

---

Edit: `access_granted` flag is useless, you could do just:

```
username = input("Enter username:")
password = input("Enter password:")

if username in userinfo_dict.keys() and userinfo_dict[username] == password:
    loggedin()
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Comment: @MissComputing Not really. I left it there because I don't know how you are using it in the rest of your program.

Comment: @MissComputing you could keep the flags and place the username and password inputs inside the while loop, with the print statement in the else block if you want the user to be able to have multiple attempts to sign in.

Comment: Thanks Henry - I'm just about to post, if I'm allowed, another question, that is along the same lines. I'm really after efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I concur to the above. The problem is with getting the non-existing key. Try it either:

- via [try/except block](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions),
- via [dictionary get() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm).

Also the code requires a bit of refactoring e.g.:

- checking to False via 'is' a;
- accessgranted==True should be assignment, not comparison;
- the logic of loop had to be changed as well.

See below:

```
username = input("Enter username:")
password = input("Enter password:")

access_granted = False
while access_granted is False:
    if userinfo_dict.get(username) == password:
        # loggedin()
        access_granted = True
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
        break
# main()
```

Comment: er, the idiomatic way is to simply check `while not access_granted:`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always use `dictionary.get(key)` instead of `dictionary[key]`. The former is safe for when keys don't exist (like in this case) while the latter will throw an error.

```
if userinfo_dict.get(username) == password: # returns None is key doesn't exist
    loggedin()
    accessGranted=True
else:
    break
```

Comment: actually - I tried if username in userinfo_dict.keys() and userinfo_dict[username]==password: which works. Using your suggested answer comes up with an error when you try it with correct username and wrong password. Won't downvote - but you may want to check

Comment: can you post the error/example you ran? can't seem to re-create locally

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that you have entered the value "ee" for the user name, but there is no user named "ee" (that is, no key-value pair with the key "ee") in the dictionary.  This is the expected result when attempting to get the value for a non-existent key.

The correct python idiom for testing for the presence of a key is:

```
if user_name in userinfo_dict:
```